# echo $PATH shows path to python scripts, but they cannot be executed

Tags: scripting, python, path

I am new to using the shell, and wanted to create a directory in `$HOME` where I can put all my python scripts, set a path to that directory, so that I can go into any folder on my Mac and execute those scripts on certain files, without the script having to be contained inside the same directory as the file that would serve as the input to those scripts.

I have read around and added this to my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/python_functions/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I added a script called `sleep_plotter.py` to `python_functions/bin`, which is where I am planning to put all my future scripts as well.

However, when I navigate to the folder that contains the text file I want to use as input to that script, and type `python sleep_plotter.py 113testCtM113.txt`, the last argument being the text file input to my script, I get the following error message:

```
python: can't open file 'sleep_plotter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I call the path using `echo $PATH`, I see this:

```
/Users/myname/python_functions/bin:
```

From this, I gathered that python is looking in that directory when I execute a Python command, so it should be able to run `sleep_plotter.py` even when I am in a different folder that doesn't contain this file.

I am using Mac OSX 10.11.2, zsh, and Anaconda 2.3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATH` variable defines the directories which are searched when executing commands. However when you execute `python sleep_plotter.py 113testCtM113.txt`, `sleep_plotter.py` is an argument to the `python` program (command). Shell uses `PATH` to find `python`, but not its arguments.

You can add an executable attribute to your script:

```
$ chmod +x /Users/myname/python_functions/bin/sleep_plotter.py
```

Add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) sequence to the top (first line) of your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And run the script directly as a command:

```
$ sleep_plotter.py 113testCtM113.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense! But when I followed what you said, I get this error message: `name 'chmod' is not defined`...

Comment: That's an OS shell command.

Comment: After closing and re-opening the iTerm, it doesn't work anymore, and I get `zsh: command not found: sleep_plotter.py`, even after executing `chmod +x /Users/myname/python_functions/bin/sleep_plotter.py`. The shebang sequence is still at the top of my script..

Comment: You don't need to repeat `chmod`. Check if the folder is still defined in `$PATH`

Comment: It works. For some reason my $PATH contained `python_function` instead of `python_functions`.. Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend python to search through additional directories, then you need to do two things: set the PYTHONPATH variable and use the `-m` option in Python.

In `~/.zshrc` (note that there is no `$PATH` in there):

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/python_functions/bin"
```

And in the terminal use:

```
python -m sleep_plotter 113testCtM113.txt
```

which as much typing as you did before, because you have to leave out the `.py` extension on the python file.